# How to pull data from iOS app by initiating the call in watchOS complication?

Tags: watchos, apple-watch-complication

I am currently placing

```
[[WCSession defaultSession] transferUserInfo:applicationDict];
```

Inside of my Complication Controller, within

```
getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication
```

I know that this is not the correct place for it, but I am a loss as to where and when I should begin pulling info from iOS.  This seems to be sparsely documented.

My goal is to have it make an initial call to a function in iOS which will fetch data from a server and respond by placing that data into a class on the watchOS side.  I also want to be able to update it periodically afterward.

So how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't recommend requesting data from the phone within 'getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication'. Apple recommends you get data in

```
handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>)
```

in your ExtensionDelegate or push the data to the watch in a backgroundRefreshTask on the iOS side using

```
WCSession.default.transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo(_)
```

within

```
application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)
```